# What does this regexp mean - "\p{Lu}"?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I stumble across this regular expression in c# I would like to port to javascript, and I do not understand the following:

```
[-.\p{Lu}\p{Ll}0-9]+
```

The part I have a hard time with is of course `\p{Lu}`. All regexp websites I visited never mention this modifier.

Any idea?

Comment: see the description at the right side in this link http://regex101.com/r/lG2nG9/1

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

Comment: Always one more website ! thank you for regex101 which is very cool. Never saw this website before. post it as answer? Or I'll delete the question if it is too obvious (but was not for me)

Comment: You could use `\p{L}` instead of `\p[Lu}\p{Ll}`

Comment: For C#/.Net regular expression syntax consider visiting MSDN - [Regular Expression Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and subsequent [Character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

These are considered [Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) properties.

The Unicode property `\p{L}` — shorthand for `\p{Letter}` will match any kind of letter from any language. Therefore, `\p{Lu}` will match an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant. And, the opposite `\p{Ll}` will match a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant.

Concisely, this would match any [lowercase/uppercase that has a variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case) from any language:

```
AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz
```

Comment: could you explain `uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant`? Mainly the `lowecase variant`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  It means that in the unicode alphabet a character can be rendered in both uppercase and lowercase, and to match only the uppercase version of that letter. It also implies that there are uppercase characters that have no lowercase version.

Comment: So then would `\p{L}` potentially match some characters that the given regex wouldn't? Namely those that don't have an uppercase or lowercase variant?

Comment: Think about the lowercase German character `ß`. Since this letter cannot occur at the beginning of a word, there is never going to be an uppercase variant for it.

Comment: @OnlineCop Well, good thing if you used `\p{L}`, instead of maintaining a hardcoded list yourself, as there is now an uppercase `ẞ`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%C3%9F) has details.