# Matching international letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex to match words that start with uppercase letters in text:

```
var mathes = text.match(/[a-z]*[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g);
```

This works fine except when matching international letters they are being ignored. This thread [What does this regexp mean - "\p{Lu}"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977309/what-does-this-regexp-mean-plu) suggests using the form \p{Lu} and \p{Ll} so I would assume it to work like this:

```
var mathes = text.match(/\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}+p{Ll}*/g);
```

However the matching of uppercase letters stops working.

How can I include matching international letters in words starting with uppercase?

Comment: Use `u` flag, `var mathes = text.match(/\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}+p{Ll}*/gu);`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the suggestion. However I am getting the error Unknown property: Ll ... I also tried using the same pattern with XRegExp and I still get the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You have a typo in the `\p{Ll}` that I copy/pasted into the top comment. Use `.match(/\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}+\p{Ll}*/gu)`, it works.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am getting the same error in the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/match-regex-js-forked-rp0ej?file=/src/index.js Can you see there if I am missing something?

Comment: The environment is not ECMAScript 2018 compliant. See [a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/0d8u1whz/). This won't work in Safari though.